# Puppeteer. Cannot get node property in evaluate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

How does one find a nondescript radio button element and click it in puppeteer?

I have seen a lot of articles saying, "just use evaluate() and then click it" or similar, and that just doesn't work in my scenario.

Here is what I have:

```
page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));

await page.evaluate(() => {
    let container = document.getElementById('container');
    let options = container.getElementsByClassName('labels');

    // OPTIONS GIVES ME AN ARRAY OF JSHandle@node.

    if (options.length > 0) {
        for (let radio of options) {
            let value = radio.value;
            console.log(value);
        }
    }
});
```

I have no idea what to do. value is always empty.

I need to know its `value` in order to know whether to click it or not. I intend to pass in a variable to evaluate and then click the right one based on that variable.

If I simply put `radio.click()` in the for loop, it works in that it clicks each one of the elements and always ends on the last one being selected. So I know `click()` works. How do I determine WHICH one to click, and choose it?

Here are the 2 radio button elements as HTML:

```
<input name="choice" value="accept" class="checkbox" type="radio">

<input name="choice" value="reject" class="checkbox" type="radio">
```

Comment: your radios have have the class checkbox but the elements you are looping through have the class labels

Comment: Oh my actual god. I have spent 2 hours looking at this googling every possible answer. You are absolutely right. Its looping the labels, not the containing inputs. I keep reading `for (let radio of options)` as it being the radio buttons within. End . Me .

Comment: I think matters were made worse by being able to click the containing label, and it still checked the radio button. Confirming to me that it was the radio button.

Comment: Some times we get so used to the code we are looking that we can't see these simple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use getElementsByName?

```
page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));

await page.evaluate(() => {
    let options = container.getElementsByName('choice');

    if (options.length > 0) {
        for (let radio of options) {
            let value = radio.value;
            console.log(value);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This does indeed fix my problem, however it's not the reason behind the problem. See comments by @Ramon Portella above. Will mark this as the answer anyway as technically this now works.

Comment: Yeah, he was partially right, should have put his comment as an answer :-)

Comment: Was so engrossed in the console log from the wrong node, that I ended up deep diving JSHandles' and spent a lot of time working out what they are and why they were being used. I guess not entirely a waste of time as I learnt something new :)